# postgres array of range type check include

Tags: postgresql, range

Is there a way to check if array of range includes another array of range in postgres

```
create table t(f int4range[])
insert into t values(array[int4range(1, 3), int4range(5,8)]);


select * from t where myincludes(f, array[int4range(1,2), int4range(5,6)]
```

this SQL will return the data:

```
| [NumericRange(1, 3, '[)'), NumericRange(5, 8, '[)')] |
+------------------------------------------------------+
```

the array length might not be the same. but the range won't have overlap.

One way I can come up with is loop over the arguments then check if there is any range that contains the argument like this:

```
for i in arguments:
  contains := false
  for j in data:
    if j contains i:
      contains = true
      break // check the next argument
  if contains == false:
    return false
```

But I wonder if there another way I can achieve this.
Thanks!

Comment: Is this code a piece of your `myincludes` function? It's good to post full MVCE, so attach the full code to all things that you're using.

Answer (score 0):

You can `unnest()` and join both arrays. If there is a pair in that result, where one range doesn't contain the other, to check this you can use the `@>` operator, it's not a match. You can use a `NOT EXISTS` in the outer queries `WHERE` clause to check, that no such pair exists.

```
SELECT *
       FROM t
       WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                                FROM unnest(f) WITH ORDINALITY un1(f, o)
                                     FULL JOIN unnest(array[int4range(1,2), int4range(5,6)]) WITH ORDINALITY un2(f, o)
                                               ON un2.o = un1.o
                                WHERE NOT coalesce(un1.f @> un2.f, false));
```